# Copy/paste text in .exe python project

Tags: python-3.x, copy-paste

I've made a code that turns text into hidden messages (ex. text: "how are you?" into: "h\w ]r[ y>?") it's nothing fancy but I had the idea while learning the basics and wanted to see if it worked. 
Then I exported my .py project to .exe and it works but in that window I can't copy or paste text which means I can translate text but can't use it to send as message or something.

Some friends told me that there should be a simple solution to this, something like function that I could just import into project.py but sadly none of them know exactly how to do it.

Comment: Friends don't tell friends something is simple if they are, in fact, unable to do so themselves. Your title and question states your copying problem has something to do with the fact that you made it a standalone executable. So this works in your original Python script?

Comment: Yes, it does. For what it's supposed to do it works great the only problem is that it just gives me translated text which I can't use. I used pyinstaller to turn it into .exe

Comment: Let me guess (because you are, uh, kind of *sparse* with factual details). You show your translated text with a message box, right? You do not say what kind of Windows interface you are using; but surely it also has an option to display a text inside a window that allows you to select, edit, and/or copy text? Windows interface libraries are expected to have such a thing as it's a quite common request.

Comment: Sorry, as I said I'm quite new to this. So when I start the .exe file it opens up and looks exactly like command prompt. It prompts you to enter a message and when I do so and click enter it just spits out the translated text in a new row and immediately prompts you to enter another message... When I try ctlr v or ctrl c it acts exactly like cmd.

Comment: Honestly I wish I could just show you, I know this must be frustrating for you. Sorry